# Two tier horizontal (dropline) menu for sharepoint top navigation bar

Tags: navigation

How can i make the sharepoint top navigation bar (Sharepoint:Aspmenu) two tier, like the menu below?

[image]

you can see the menu [here](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/simple_dropline.html) or [here](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/pro_dropline7.html) or [here](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/pro-dropline-9.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wordpress solution, but I guess it can be also done with HTML&CSS only. 
http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/02/12/creating-two-tiered-conditional-navigation-in-wordpress/
I tried in on wordpress and it worked perfectly.
Good luck;)